# Create an obstacle with GKPolygonObstacle

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gamekit

I'm trying to manually create an obstacle like so:

```
let points = [vector_float2(-25, 50), vector_float2(25, 50), vector_float2(25, -50), vector_float2(-25, -50)]

let obs = GKPolygonObstacle(points: points, count: points.count)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[vector_float2]' to expected argument type
'UnsafeMutablePointer<vector_float2>' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<float2>')
```

I'm not sure how to convert a vector_float2 array to an UnsafeMutablePointer

I've Googled but found no results, and looked through Apple's projects but couldn't seem to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error -- I needed to do this:

let pts = [vector_float2(0, 5), vector_float2(10, 10)]
//just float2 also works I think

let obstacle = GKPolygonObstacle(UnsafeMutablePointer(pts), count: pts.count)